# How to check the state of a toggle button from another class

Tags: android, togglebutton

```
 final Switch tButton = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        final SharedPreferences Switch = getSharedPreferences(PREFS,0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Switch.edit();
        tButtonChecked = Switch.getBoolean("userMessage", false);
        tButton.setChecked(tButtonChecked);
        tButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    editor.putBoolean("userMessage", isChecked);
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("userMessage", isChecked);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

How to check the state of this toggle button/switch button (is it checked or not) from another class?

Comment: What kind of class? Is it tied to your activity? Be more specific about what you want to achieve please.

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there.

In your other class, do this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean isToggleButtonChecked = prefs.getBoolean("userMessage", false); // second argument is the value if the preference doesn't exist.
```